# What is the correlation coefficient I should choose? Spearman or Pearson? Dataset consists of 2000+ entries, less likely to be Kendall

Tags: correlation

[image]

I am doing the exercise, to analysie a dataset. Kilometres are:
1: <1000
2:1000-15000
3:15000-20000
4:20000-25000
5:>25000

Comment: Binning the kilometers like you did loses information. Perhaps try plotting the measured x-values against the y-values, rather than using the kilometer bins. Your graph makes it look like a categorical x-variable and that correlation will not be so helpful.

Comment: okay, thanks. But if instead of Kilometres there would be Ordinal variable like 'First grade' , 'Second grade' , would it be okay to use spearman? And also, in this case doing any type of correlation is meaningful, isn't it?

Comment: There are ordinal variables like that, yes, and the rank-based Spearman correlation would make sense for such data.

Answer (score 1):

Kilometers on the x axis are no longer metric but they are certainly of ordinal scale niveau. Thus a Pearson correlation is not possible and spearman correlation is in order. You can use Spearman correlation on metric data but not Pearson on non-metric data.

Please let me note that your plot is not a good one: Most of the data cannot be seen because of overplotting and the tiny part that you can see makes you believe you can see a pattern in the data. It is thus misleading. You could jitter the data or you could draw a violin plot or a number of density plots. All of that can be done within `ggplot2`, which I suppose you used for plotting.

Also: Most data are small values with only little large data. You should consider a logarithmic y axis for a jitteres scatter plot or a violin plot.

Assuming you used `ggplot2` in `R` here are some hints to play around with:

```
x <- gl(5,400)
y <- c(abs(rnorm(400))^4.3, abs(rnorm(400))^4.6, abs(rnorm(400))^4.0, 
       abs(rnorm(400)^3.8), abs(rnorm(400)^3.5))
d <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
          geom_point()
plot(p1)
plot(p1 + coord_trans(y = "log10"))
p2 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
          geom_jitter(width=.1)
          
plot(p2)  
plot(p2 + coord_trans(y = "log10"))

p3 <- ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
          geom_violin() + 
          coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 10))
plot(p3)
```